# How to change a button's background color

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, storyboard, interface-builder

In this Swift code that I have greatly simplified for posting here:

```
@IBOutlet weak var outTrig: UIButton!
@IBAction func actTriggerCameras(_ sender: UIButton) {
    Trig()
}

Trig(){
    outTrig.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemRed
}
```

I attempt to change the Storyboard button's background color to give feedback to the user that touching it registered with the system. But the background color does not change in the iPhone 14 where this code is run. What do I need to do make this change show on the User Interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 15 introduced `UIButton.Configuration`

By default, when you add a button in Storyboard, the button **Style** is set to `Plain`.

[image]

If the style is `Plain`, `Gray`, `Tinted` or `Filled`:

[image]

you have to use its `.configuration` property to make changes:

```
var cfg = outTrig.configuration
cfg?.baseBackgroundColor = .systemRed
outTrig.configuration = cfg
```

If you change the style to `Default`:

[image]

[image]

you can then use the "older" methods:

```
outTrig.backgroundColor = .systemRed
```

See Apple's docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration).